# Very long horizontal scroll to the left in my page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Wordpress page, there is a scroll bar at the bottom, which takes the page to an empty region to the left. I tried to inspect the element causing this but I couldn't.

Why does this happen? And how can I investigate the cause of this?

Thank you.

Comment: In case you put a -1, explain why.

Comment: I'd guess that you got some downvotes because your question didn't include the URL of the page that was misbehaving.

Comment: @andrewsi I did put the url in a comment and I removed it after the problem was solved. I can't keep it because it has to do with my safty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed you have left: -999em and some other declarations that pull your items way to the left. Usually this is done so the items are hidden from the viewport, which is fine.

To fix this issue, simply add `overflow: hidden` to your body {} in your stylesheet file, for example:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```